# What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'

Tags: sdk, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5.1/gradle-7.5.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about the issue regarding Hyperskill, the JetBrains educational platform, not being able to check your solution to a problem due to weird problems with Gradle. I'm assuming that because I encountered it, too, on October 23th, 2022, as well as many users from Russia (or who use a Russian IP-address).

I have concluded that this problem may occur on JetBrains' side from time to time, so I'll post a few solutions to it, including the ones that the other guys have come up with that worked for them.

---

### Solution #1: Use VPN

This is the solution that worked for me personally. I found that the seed of the problem was in my network not being able to successfully fetch the **hs-gradle-plugin-release-v1.1-g905ba16-19.jar** package from [https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-gradle-plugin/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-gradle-plugin-release-v1.1-g905ba16-19.jar](https://%20https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-gradle-plugin/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-gradle-plugin-release-v1.1-g905ba16-19.jar). When I would visit the link above manually, by myself, it either wouldn't show anything or would display

> Build failed. See the log at jitpack.io

At last, when I tried to visit the link while being connected from the UK, the US or Netherlands, a download window would pop up.
Thus, I recommend trying to connect from one of the countries above, then open the 'Gradle' tab in IntelliJ IDEA and press the 'Reload All Gradle Projects' button. You don't need to manually alter any settings/preferences in IDE regarding your network connection.

---

### Solution #2: Edit *build.gradle*

This is the solution I had found online and the one later proposed by JetBrains Academy Support Team when I contacted them, though it didn't work for me.
That's what they have advised:

1. Open *build.gradle* in your project folder
2. Replace the line **testImplementation 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT'** with **testImplementation 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:master-SNAPSHOT'**.

---

### Solution #3: Additional tinkering

If none of the above helped you, you could try another solution that some people have come up with:

1. Go to site https://jitpack.io/#hyperskill/hs-gradle-plugin/v1.1
2. Get config for v1.1 and follow the instructions on that page
3. Downgrade JDK from 17 to 16

---

The problem seems to have vanished for now, as I don't need a VPN to bypass the problem anymore; everything works fine now. But, as I have stated, users have reported that problem several times before, so you can always try the steps above and see if one of them works for you.